# Supports of elements in $\ell_\infty$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

It is idle curiosity that makes me ask so apologies for no motivation.

Let $X$ be an infinite-dimensional, closed subspace of $\ell_\infty$. Can we find a non-zero element $x\in X$ such that $x(n)\geqslant 0$ for all $n$?

Comment: Not necessarily. Let $X$ be the set of vectors satisfying $x_{2n}=-x_{2n-1}$ for each $n$.